# unable to implement kaminari gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari, ruby-on-rails-7

I have error implementing kaminari gem for pagination

I have the same issue here. I am using Rails 7

```
I have alread add gem 'kaminari', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.2' to my Genfile and run bundle install
```

```js
blogs_controller.rb

def index
   @blogs = Blog.page(params[:page]).per(5)
 end

View

<div class="col-md-8 blog-main">
  <%= render @blogs %>
  <%= paginate @blogs %>
</div>



Error

ActionController::UnfilteredParameters in Blogs#index
Showing /home/emmy/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb where line #14 raised:

unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: your log show that your current kaminari gem version is `/kaminari-0.16.3/`.

Comment: Do I have to use a different version of Kaminari?

Comment: give it a try ! the `UnfilteredParameters` raised when the method `ActionController::Parameters#to_h` called on unpermitted params, i don't have the source of version 0.16.3 but in the gem `kaminari` version 1.22 i only see the method `to_unsafe_h` called instead.